# Laravel 5.7 : Collection ; getting the interface type instead of the model type

Tags: php, laravel, collections, laravel-5.7

I have two models : `Guest` and `User`, both of them are part of the `Notifiable` interface. In my mailing command, I create a collection that I send to a `dispatch` function.

```php
$notifiables = Notification::where('created_at', '>', $from)
                           ->whereNull('read_at')
                           ->get()
                           ->map(function($notification){
                                return $notification->notifiable; })
                           ->filter(function($notifiable){
                                return $notifiable->isRecievingEmails(); });
```

It works perfectly if I only have one model type in my collection (i.e. a collection of only `User` or only `Guest`). But if I have a mixed collection... I have this error :

```
Queueing collections with multiple model types is not supported.
```

Both `User` and `Guest` are both also a `Notifiable` type. How can I transform both my `User` and my `Guest`types into a `Notifiable` type inside my Collection ?

Edit 1: I'm looking at the binding thing in Laravel but this is very weird for me with a Collection.